# Truly select first record

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot find this anywhere but with the following sql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Orders` ORDER BY ID LIMIT 0, 10
```

MySQL returns 9 records starting with the second record. Why is it not showing me the first record?

ID is an autoincremented field so it is skipping the first record with an ID of 8 and starting with the record with an ID of 9

Comment: This should return 10 rows -- unless the table has fewer than 10 rows.  It should not be skipping any rows.  You are probably misinterpreting the results.

Comment: I bet your other IDs got deleted. Does `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ID < 8` return any results?

Comment: See I completely agree, this shouldn't be happening. SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ID < 8 returns returns the first row of data.

Comment: Maybe your table and/or MySQL is trashed. Does `OPTIMIZE TABLE Orders` and then running it again fix anything? Does restarting the server? Is it an older version?

Comment: Can you use a service like [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) to create a live reproducible example for the community to take a look at?

Comment: How many rows does the table have? nine?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour

Comment: The Table was indeed corrupt, after and optimize command, everything was normal!!